# Grouping dataframe by each 6 hour and generating a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have this dataframe (type could be 1 or 2):

```
user_id | timestamp      | type
1       | 2015-5-5 12:30 | 1
1       | 2015-5-5 14:00 | 2
1       | 2015-5-5 15:00 | 1
```

I want to group my data by six hours and when doing this I want to keep `type` as:

- `1` (if there is only 1 within that 6 hour frame)
- `2` (if there is only 2 within that 6 hour frame) or
- `3` (if there was both 1 and 2  within that 6 hour frame)

Here is the my code:

```
df = df.groupby(['user_id', pd.TimeGrouper(freq=(6,'H'))]).mean()
```

which produces:

```
user_id | timestamp      | type
1       | 2015-5-5 12:00 | 4
```

However, I want to get `3` instead of 4. I wonder how can I replace the `mean()` in my `groupby` code to produce the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [54]: df.groupby(['user_id', pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='6H')]) \
           .agg({'type':lambda x: x.unique().sum()})
Out[54]:
                             type
user_id timestamp
1       2015-05-05 12:00:00     3
```

PS it'll work only with given types: (`1`, `2`) as their sum is `3`

Another data set:

```
In [56]: df
Out[56]:
   user_id           timestamp  type
0        1 2015-05-05 12:30:00     1
1        1 2015-05-05 14:00:00     1
2        1 2015-05-05 15:00:00     1
3        1 2015-05-05 20:00:00     1

In [57]: df.groupby(['user_id', pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='6H')]).agg({'type':lambda x: x.unique().sum()})
Out[57]:
                             type
user_id timestamp
1       2015-05-05 12:00:00     1
        2015-05-05 18:00:00     1
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!